# Is Multilingual App Toolkit compatible with multi target framework?

Tags: c#, multitargeting, multilingual-app-toolkit

I'm trying to use MAT with a package I'm building (in C#).
I can enable MAT when my package targets only one framework (for exemple .NET core 3.1)

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  <NeutralLanguage>fr</NeutralLanguage>
</PropertyGroup>
```

but if I choose to target multi framework, the option is disabled

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.1;net5.0</TargetFrameworks>
  <NeutralLanguage>fr</NeutralLanguage>
</PropertyGroup>
```

(note the 's' at the end of framework)

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did an experiment and I found that you have to have a single `<TargetFramework>` setting only:

- to enable MAT for the project
- to add new language

As soon as you have the language-specific `.resx` and `.xlf` files you can restore the multi-targeting by setting `<TargetFrameworks>` node.

I successfully

- added new string resources and their translations
- built/ran the solution

when multi-targeting was on.